# iOS Xcode Update altering Prototype cells

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, prototype, swrevealviewcontroller

I was working on an app for iOS7 in Xcode 5 but since upgrading to iOS 8 and Xcode 6 I've been getting some issues.

Basically, I am using SWRevealViewController in order to create a sliding sidebar for my app. This sidebar has numerous rows which have labels and pictures in them. They were appearing fine before but now they appear as shown below:

http://postimg.org/image/4ddj5n6df/

They are all bunched together. I am also getting several 'Missing constraints' errors as well as two 'Scrollable Content Size' errors.

Could it be that SWRevealViewController plugin hasn't been upgraded properly to work with iOS 8? Is there an alternative?

```
@interface foodforteethSidebarViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *menuItems;

@end

@implementation foodforteethSidebarViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.4f alpha:0.2f];

    _menuItems = @[@"home", @"title", @"cereals", @"meats", @"snacks", @"dairy", @"drinks", @"desserts", @"fastfoods", @"fruitandveg", @"sauces", @"confectionaries", @"misc"];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.menuItems count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *CellIdentifier = [self.menuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}

- (void) prepareForSegue: (UIStoryboardSegue *) segue sender: (id) sender
{
    // Set the title of navigation bar by using the menu items
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    UINavigationController *destViewController = (UINavigationController*)segue.destinationViewController;
    destViewController.title = [[_menuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] capitalizedString];

    if ( [segue isKindOfClass: [SWRevealViewControllerSegue class]] ) {
        SWRevealViewControllerSegue *swSegue = (SWRevealViewControllerSegue*) segue;

        swSegue.performBlock = ^(SWRevealViewControllerSegue* rvc_segue, UIViewController* svc, UIViewController* dvc) {

            UINavigationController* navController = (UINavigationController*)self.revealViewController.frontViewController;
            [navController setViewControllers: @[dvc] animated: NO ];
            [self.revealViewController setFrontViewPosition: FrontViewPositionLeft animated: YES];
        };

    }

}

@end
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the interesting part of SWRevealViewController code? In particular the table view data source and delegate methods.

Comment: I've attached the code from the .m file for my sidebar. The library itself is available online: https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController